# escaping user input using express.js

Tags: mongodb, express, escaping

When a user fills out a form how do I go about escaping the user input in `express.js`?

Does `express.js` do this by default?  I can't find a source.

Do I have to use a third-party module like `express-validator.js`?

**UPDATE**
I figured out the difference between escaping and validating.

What I wanted to do was escape user input but what I should be doing is validating it, making sure it's in a valid format and then escape the output to the form if it is not valid providing the user exactly what they inputted.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= some_html %>` will automatically escape it. `<%- some_html %>` will output html intact.

Comment: I'm trying to assess user input.  A user fills out a form I want to 'escape' their input before I insert into a database

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what kind of escaping do you need to do? Express will automatically decode (not unescape) the query string for you and make it available as `req.query`. URL params will also be unencoded for you automatically.

If you need to escape HTML that includes user input when rendering, you should do that via your template engine. Most template engines such as jade (`= value`) or handlebars or mustache (`{{value}}`) will escape HTML by default, and require an explicit syntax to pass data through unescaped ( `!= value` in jade or `{{{value}}}` in handlebars/mustache).

Comment: Escaping user input from a login form, say.  If a user tries to get fancy and input @$%^&*! I would want to 'escape' (validate, not sure which terminology to use).

Comment: You mean validate, not escape. Express doesn't do any validation for you. You can just use regular expressions or validation code if your data must be in a certain format or range. There are also some libraries you could use, but start with coding it yourself so you know what you are doing.